# bash cURL POST not working?

Tags: linux, bash, curl, urlencode

I'm writing a script to check updates on this website : http://www.adm.uwaterloo.ca/infocour/CIR/SA/under.html

I need to select a subject and course number on the page and submit this in order to get the data I want. I tried the following on terminal :

```
curl -d "subject=CO" -d "cournum=250" -X POST http://www.adm.uwaterloo.ca/infocour/CIR/SA/under.html > old.html
```

The old.html file shows the html for the page and it seems as if the post request didn't work. Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong? And how should I do it so I can get the page after selecting the appropriate course and submitting the form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the hood if you click see page source, it `GET` request not the `POST` request, so your `curl` command should be something like below.

```
curl http://www.adm.uwaterloo.ca/cgi-bin/cgiwrap/infocour/salook.pl?level=under&sess=1189&subject=ACTSC&cournum=
```

Here, sess=`1189` and subject=`ACTSC` are random values I picked to see.